# Alter Header Label for Show/Hide Javascript

Tags: javascript, show-hide

http://jsfiddle.net/YaMhn/8/

^^^^Take a look and see if you can help solve this

Ok so I added the label showhide to my script

```
function showHide(lbl)
{
if(document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display == "none")
{
    lbl.innerHTML="Hide";
    document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display="";
}
else
{
    lbl.innerHTML="Show";
    document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display="none";
}
}

function showhide(id) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
obj = document.getElementById(id);
if (obj.style.display == "") {
  obj.style.display = "none";
} else {
  obj.style.display = "";
}
  }
}

function hide(id) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
obj = document.getElementById(id);
if (obj.style.display == "none") {
  obj.style.display = "none";
} else {
  obj.style.display = "none";
}
  }
}

function hideall(id1,id2,id3,id4) {
  var status1 = document.getElementById(id1).style.display; 
  var status2 = document.getElementById(id2).style.display; 
  var status3 = document.getElementById(id3).style.display; 
  var status4 = document.getElementById(id4).style.display; 
  if ((status1 == 'none') || (status2 == 'none') || (status3 = 'none') || (status4 = 'none')) {
hide(id1);  hide(id2); hide(id3); hide(id4); return;
  }
  if ((status1 != 'none') || (status2 != 'none') || (status3 != 'none') || (status4 != 'none')) {
hide(id1);  hide(id2); hide(id3); hide(id4); return;
  }
}

function show(id) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
obj = document.getElementById(id);
if (obj.style.display == "") {
  obj.style.display = "";
} else {
  obj.style.display = "";
}
  }
}

function showall(id1,id2,id3, id4) {
  var status1 = document.getElementById(id1).style.display; 
  var status2 = document.getElementById(id2).style.display; 
  var status3 = document.getElementById(id3).style.display; 
  var status4 = document.getElementById(id4).style.display;
  if ((status1 == 'none') || (status2 == 'none') || (status3 = 'none') || (status4 = 'none')) {
show(id1);  show(id2); show(id3); show(id4); return;
  }
  if ((status1 != 'none') || (status2 != 'none') || (status3 != 'none') || (status4 != 'none')) {
show(id1);  show(id2); show(id3); show(id4); return;
  }
}
```

Here is my Header code:

```
Header #1: (titled Runway Information    Click to Expand/Close)
<div style="background-color:black; width:80%; cursor:pointer;hand" onClick="showhide('id1'); return(false);"><table width="100%"><tr><td width=80% align=left><font color="white" size="4"><strong>&nbsp;Runway Information</strong></font></td><td align=right><div id='mydiv' style='display:none'></div></td></tr></table></div>
```

The Header works prefectly, shows and hides just as I coded. But I want it to say "Show" when hidden and "Hide" when shown.

Previously it was written like this:
     Click to Expand/Close

The problem is the new showHide(lbl) does not work as intended.

What do I need to change?

Comment: so... change the `innerHTML`, what's the big deal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made you an example : http://jsfiddle.net/YaMhn/

Comment: Thank you for the example. My question is how do I alter the label by clicking the Header DIV?

Comment: Above is a link of what I am working on... take a look and see if you can help

Comment: Im really close to the answer. Take a look at this, the only issue im having now, is alternating the "Show" and "Hide" when I click "Show All" or "Hide All" http://jsfiddle.net/YaMhn/12/

Comment: Use the same logic , the issue is [object].innerHTML='something !!';

Comment: Im not following. Gotta take baby steps with me. New to Javascript.

Comment: Well , try to read it line by line , for sure it's not the perfect solution , but as you newbie this is good for you .. http://jsfiddle.net/YaMhn/16/ .. i would suggest you to try to learn jQuery

Answer (score 2):

It is simple -- use `innerHTML`:

```
style.display="block"
innerHTML="click here to expand"
```

and to hide:

```
style.display="hide"
innerHTML="click here to close"
```

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The only change I made was else to else if, and it is now fixed.

http://jsfiddle.net/YaMhn/18/

Thank You Ashraf for the help. I would upvote you but I only have a 13 rep lol.